# Unable to install cordova-android@10.0.0

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-android

I was trying to update my cordova android version to cordova-android@10.0.0 . I tried the below command:

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android@10.0.1
```

But I am getting an error while adding the platform as below:

```
cordova platform add android@10.0.1
(node:12912) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@10.0.1
Adding android project...
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
        Path: platforms\android
        Package: com.sundewapps.nurikabe
        Name: Islands
        Activity: MainActivity
        Android target: android-30

ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir 'platforms\android\app\src\main'
```

This is the error message in the above console output **ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir 'platforms\android\app\src\main'**

Did anyone face the issue and can help with a solution?

Comment: What's your Cordova version and node verison?

Comment: Cordova version is 10.0.0 and node version is 10.17.1

Comment: Update your nodejs